# CASE-Statement in WHERE-Clause | SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case-when

Hi I have following Table with the current month `'Month'`:

```
+---------------+
| current_Month |
+---------------+
|            12 |
+---------------+
```

And I have another Table with workers `'Workers'`

```
+--------+--------------------------+
|  Name  | Month_joined_the_company |
+--------+--------------------------+
| Peter  |                       12 |
| Paul   |                        9 |
| Sarah  |                        5 |
| Donald |                       12 |
+--------+--------------------------+
```

I now want, based on my Month table, Display all workers which joined the company untill the previous month 
the current month is 10 I would like to have this output

```
+--------+--------------------------+
|  Name  | Month_joined_the_company |
+--------+--------------------------+
| Paul   |                        9 |
| Sarah  |                        5 |
+--------+--------------------------+
```

But on the end of the year, I would like to include all workers even thos which month is equal with the current month

```
+--------+--------------------------+
|  Name  | Month_joined_the_company |
+--------+--------------------------+
| Peter  |                       12 |
| Paul   |                        9 |
| Sarah  |                        5 |
| Donald |                       12 |
+--------+--------------------------+
```

I now have this Statement, but it does not work...

```
SELECT * 
FROM workers 
WHERE     
  CASE
        WHEN (SELECT TOP (1) Current_Month FROM Month) = 12
        THEN (Month_joined_the_company <= (SELECT TOP (1) Current_Month FROM Month))
        ELSE (Month_joined_the_company < (SELECT TOP (1) Current_Month FROM Month))
    END
```

But this does not work and I get an error. Can someone help me, how I can use CASE in a WHERE-Clause

Comment: Its called a case *expression*, which means it can only return an atomic value and cannot be used for program flow in this manner

Comment: Skip the `case` _expression_. It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` constructions instead in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @jarlh how can I use AND/OR to achieve my goal?

Comment: @HoneyBadger In some database systems (e.g. Postgres) it's perfectly possible for an expression to evaluate to a boolean value, and that value then be used as a condition. It's also not really correct to describe a `WHERE` clause as "program flow", even in systems that lack a boolean type so have special rules for conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select w.*
from workers w
inner join month m 
    on m.current_month = 12 
    or w.month_joined_the_company < m.current_month
```

This phrases as: if `current_month = 12` then return all workers, else just return those whose `month_joined_the_company` is stricly smaller than `current_month`.

NB: you should probably consider use date datatypes to store these values, otherwise what happens when a new year begins?